# How to extract text tagged by Stanford NER into csv?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I don't have a background in NLP or much programming, but have drifted in as I am doing research on the history of newspaper publishing. I'm wrestling with 10k+ pages of plain text that I'm having difficulty sculpting into structured data to perform more complex analyses.

I've been able to run Stanford NER on a large text file to successfully tag many of the entites I'm looking to examine. So here is my naive question: how can I extract or parse the tagged text file into a csv file - or at least separate lists for each category into some kind of structure?

For example, I'm looking at something like this:

```
The <ORGANIZATION>Committee on Education</ORGANIZATION> and the <ORGANIZATION>Philadelphia Assocation of Teachers</ORGANIZATION> offer a plan for the organization of the school in the town of <LOCATION>Erie</LOCATION>, <LOCATION>Pennsylvania</LOCATION> as it will be run by the honorable <PERSON>Williamson</PERSON> and <PERSON>Thompson</PERSON>
```

Based on looking through the vaugely similar answers to other questions on this site, I've looked at possibly using some kind of regular expression or even sed, like below, but without success.

sed -e '/^location/,/^/location/p' nertagged.txt

I've considered other options like BeautifulSoup or an XML parser (since the Stanford NER implementation can output XML), but I wonder if that isn't overkill since I'm dealing with a very limited number of tags -- basically just Person, Location, Organization. Are those my best options? What, in my ignorance, am I missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree. This isn't actually as easy to do as would be desirable, and I'll add an option to make it easier for the next version :).  But, if you use `-outputFormat inlineXML` as in your example, then the following Perl one-liner will do the trick, run on the output file, which I've called `inlineXML.out`.

```
perl -ne 'while (s/<([^>]+)>([^<]*)<[^>]+>//) { print "$2\t$1\n"; }' inlineXML.out
```

This actually puts a tab between columns not a comma.  Most spreadsheets will read that fine. If you really want a comma, you can replace the `\t` above with `,` but you may well end up with problems if some of the entities include commas, such as perhaps `University of California , Davis`.

Comment: I never say a proper thank you for this. It does exactly what I need--very grateful. I'd love to see this in the next version. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer documents the new functionality for doing this that was added in version 3.5 of Stanford NER in 2014. There is a new `outputFormat` of `tabbedEntities`. This format was custom-designed to be
helpful for people who would like to dump the output into a spreadsheet
and then to work from there. It is an interesting mixed textual/column
data representation, which we hope people find useful. The whole
tokenized text is presented in textual order, in 3 tab-separated
columns. Things in the first column are recognized entities, the second
column gives their category, and the third column contains all the text
between recognized entities. You should be able to easily load this file
into a spreadsheet, R, or a database, and then to do aggregation or queries
over recognized entities. Here's an example using the text shown above:

```
$ java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile jcc.txt -outputFormat tabbedEntities 2> /dev/null
        The
Committee on Education  ORGANIZATION    and the
Philadelphia Assocation of Teachers ORGANIZATION    offer a plan for the organization of the school in the town of
Erie    LOCATION    ,
Pennsylvania    LOCATION    as it will be run by the honorable
Williamson  PERSON  and
Thompson    PERSON
```